# Is there an equivalent of `to_json` for Vaex dataframes?

Tags: json, plotly-dash, vaex

I'm currently working on a Dash app to visualize large amounts of data. With scalability issues in mind, I'm trying to migrate from Pandas to the Vaex library to lazily load data and optimize recurrent scanning of the dataset (each time the user interacts with the filters, sampling thresholds, or other parameters).

Dash uses `dcc.Store` components to **store data in JSON format** which are essential to my app at the moment. So far, I was using `to_json` method to convert my Pandas dataframe objects. Unfortunately, I haven't found an equivalent for Vaex.

The built-in `.export` method doesn't support this format, as shown in error below :

```py
raise ValueError('''Unrecognized file extension. Please use .arrow, .hdf5, .parquet, .fits, or .csv to export to the particular file format.''')
```

Also, running the command `json.dump(my_vaex_df, 'my_df.json')` returns :

```
TypeError: Object of type DataFrameLocal is not JSON serializable
```

**Is there an equivalent to `to_json` for Vaex dataframe objects ?** If not, would there be an alternative to tackle this issue?

Grateful for any feedback.

Comment: Can (filtered) Vaex dataframe convert to pandas? You might have to go that route.

Comment: @PaulH Indeed, this would work with `to_pandas_df()` method. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaex has an `df.export_json()` method. It is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't spot that one... Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.